# CodeMirror: howto get paragraph text of current cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, codemirror

CodeMirror has editor.getSelection() which will get highlighted text. I wonder if it is possible to get all text of current cursor between 2 line breaks (works for linux/mac/windows)

```
This text is not selected because cursor is in next text block

Start point of selected text ....
Because cursor is here | .....
Rest of text also selected

This text is not selected ...
```

OK solved as I got one version working now:

```
$('#test').on('click', function() {
    var cur = editor.getCursor().line;
    var arr = editor.getValue().split("\n");
    var txt = '', start = 0, stop = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        t = arr[i].trim();
        len = t.length;
        if (!start) {
            if (!len) txt = '';
            if (i == cur) start = 1;
        }
        if (!stop) {
            if (start && !len) stop = 1;
            else if (len) txt += t + "\n";
        }
    }
    alert(txt);
})
```

If you have better solution, please answer below

Comment: Did you try to write some code?

Comment: Without codeMirror, I wrote basic js to move startSelect back to 2 newlines from cursor position, and endSelect to next 2 newlines. And works, but for codeMirror, I m not familiar how to customize

Comment: It seems like they have a very nice [manual](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html). Try it and add some code. It will be much easier to help after you have some basic code structured.